# How to get two or more permission from user using Facebook Graph API Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, api, graph

I want to get 2 permissions from users (`publish_stream`, `user_photos`).

When I try this

```
Facebook.login(handleLogin, {scope:’publish_stream’});
Facebook.login(handleLogin, {scope:’user_photos’});
```

Then it works, but it show a facebook login popup twice :(
Please help me, what I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/source/browse/trunk/source/api/com/facebook/graph/Facebook.as

```
Facebook.login(handleLogin, {scope:'publish_stream,user_photos'});
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/